# brownie steps to compile, deploy and interact on ropsten

Tags: brownie

I have created a smart contract and deployed it on ropsten with brownie framework.

Here are the steps I've done:

1. Run the command:

   ```
   $ brownie init projet1
   ```
2. I have created my contract in contracts/Contrat1.vy file
3. I have run:

   ```
   $ brownie compile
   ```
4. I have created an Ethereum account and I've sent some ether on it:

   ```
   $ brownie accounts generate mon_account2
   ```
5. I have created this file for deployment: scripts/deploiement.py:

   ```
     from brownie import Contrat1, accounts

     def main():
       compte = accounts.load('mon_account2')
       t = Contrat1.deploy({'from': compte})
   ```
6. I have created a project on infura and I've got a project id
7. I have created an account and an API TOKEN KEY on etherscan
8. I have run:

   ```
   $ export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=<my_infura_projectid>
   $ export ETHERSCAN_TOKEN=<my_etherscan_api_token_key>
   ```
9. I have run:

   ```
   $ brownie run deploiement --network ropsten
   ```

At this step, my contract is deployed on ropsten. Its deployment address is displayed on screen.

10. Now I want to interact with this contract. So I have run:

    ```
    $ brownie console --network ropsten
    provider = Contract.from_explorer('<my_contract's_deployment_address>')
    ```
11. I suppose I can now send transactions through provider variable.

Here are my questions:

- My infura secret was not asked. So I suppose anyone can call my infura project url ?
- Is there a way to avoid to work with Etherscan ? I have worked previously with truffle and it was not necessary to get an Etherscan account for deploying contract.
- Is there a way to avoid to export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID and ETHERSCAN_TOKEN ? Is there a way to put these values in a project configuration file ?
- When launching Contract.from_explorer, I get this error:

> ValueError: Failed to retrieve data from API: Contract source code not
> verified

How should I fix that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: you need to upload the source code at etherscan website

Comment: Is there a way to do that automaticaly from brownie command line ? And is there a way to avoid this ? Thanks

Comment: `wget` can help (or `curl`) : https://etherscan.io/sourcecode-demo.html

Comment: you don't need to verify source code in order to call a function in a contract, just deploy  it the hard way and make a `Call()`

Comment: "Deploying a Smart Contract, The Hard Way" by Gustavo Guimares (medium.com)

Comment: Thanks. Yes but how can i make a "call()", i need to instanciate my contract first

Comment: you instantiate it the hard way. Its a no brainer, just compile it and send a transaction to `nil` address.